# CocoaPods no such module with Xcode 7 Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Can't seem to import any of my pods in my project. It always tells me there is "no such module" Have tried everything that I read online and wondering if I should reinstall Xcode.

Used use_frameworks! in my pod file with the pods VideoSplashKit and Firebase. Did a pod install then opened the new xcworkspace file. Even tried adding the two libraries in my build settings.Still nothing, any idea?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpaBp.png)

[What my project looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Md9Dl.png)

Comment: What does your podfile look like?  Where are you seeing the errors?

Comment: # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!


pod 'VideoSplashKit'
pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.0'


I have also added the target end as well but it made no difference. The error occurs on my import statement when I try importing it in my viewcontroller.swift file

Answer (score 0):

Here is my temporary solution.

Add built frameworks into embedded binaries [image]

In the bridge file, change #import to @import ; [image]

By doing this, my code can use the framework in cocoapods project.

It's not the solution for this problem but just let me continue to work until the solution come.